# MySQL: adding and multiplying

Tags: mysql, sum

How can I make a query that adds and multiplies two columns?

For example:

```
id || Price per item || Items purchased
1  || 4------------------- ||     3
2  || 3.2----------------  ||     7
```

I need a query to do: 4*3 + 3.2*7 and so on... How can I do so?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT SUM(price * items_purchased)
  FROM myTable
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *, SUM(price*items) total FROM your_table
```

It will save the sum in the field `total`. You can access it in your application with that reference, just like you would access price or items.